# .load() html content into a container in a loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, load

I have a container $('#container') and I want to dynamically load several elemtents into the container.  I have a php layout called subElement.php.  So my code looks like:

```
for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
    $('#container').load('subElement.php?id='+i,function(data){});
}
```

Only one subElement.php layout is loaded in to the container.  How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: The `load` function does overwrite the contents of the elements

Comment: You should not fire 10 ajax requests at once. Make `subElement.php` return more than one element

Comment: My data is in a JSONArray...is there an easy way to pass a JSONArray to a php file?

Comment: @AH: There is no such thing as a "JSONArray".  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  You probably have a JavaScript array, nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, you should rewrite your PHP script to get all the data at once, so you only need one `.load`. Doing so will be faster and much gentler on the user's network connections.

However, since you asked us to work with what you have:

```
for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
    $('#container').append($('<span>').load('subElement.php?id='+i));
}
```

If those `<span>` elements are going to mess up your code, though, you should go with a solution like [Explosion Pills'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806644/901048) instead.

Comment: I have a JSONArray of data in the main js file.  When inside subElement.php, how can I access that JSONArray?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Answer (score 3):

`.load` will overwrite the contents each time.  Instead, you have to append them, possibly like so:

```
$.get('subElement.php?id=+1', function (data) {
   $("#container").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the loop, load() *replaces* the contents of $('#container') with the new thing that you've requested.

For efficiency, the best thing to do would be to ajax for all of the sub elements in one gulp, instead of making 10 separate HTTP requests.

Another way to do it, if for some reason you can't change the api to support getting multiple elements, is to use .get() and collect all of the answers before doing a single replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#container').append('some content')` to add to `#container`.